# How to compare arrays with different lengh?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

Doing this simple task for long time :(

I did a function, that takes an array, then it finds negative numbers, makes it positive and copy this numbers to another array.

Then it sorts first array.
Later I`m trying to compare numbers from first and second arrays and if it will be same, all this same numres will be negative again.

Example:
I entered: 6 -2 4 -5 -7, then program will return: -2 4 -5 6 -7

My code:

```
def interchanged(posled):
    otricanie = []
    for i in range(len(posled)):
        chislo = posled[i]
        if chislo < 0:
            posled[i] *= -1
            otricanie.append(posled[i])
    posled.sort()
    #print(posled)
    for i in otricanie:
        if otricanie[i] in posled:
                posled[i] *= -1
    #print(posled)
    return posled

x = interchanged(posled)
print(x)
```

Comment: This isn't very clear. Are you just trying to sort according to absolute value?

Comment: Consider naming your variables in English. Even such a simple code causes confusion. I assume it's Russian or Bulgarian expressed in Latin :)

Comment: okay, thx, i will fix it :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So you are basically trying to sort the array according to the absolute value of its elements. You can achieve this in one go using `sorted` (or `.sort` for in-place sorting) and `abs` as the [key function](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions).

```
arr = [6, -2, 4, -5, -7]
print(sorted(arr, key=abs))
```

outputs

```
[-2, 4, -5, 6, -7]
```